# Changing background on individual state when clicked

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am trying to change state colors based on clicks, and so far it is doing the entire background.

How would I get just the id of the state or location clicked and change the color based on that?

```
  require(["esri/views/View"], (View) => {
view.on("click", function (event) {
  view.hitTest(event).then(function (response) {
    if (response.results.length) {
      let graphic = response.results.filter(function (result) {
        return result.graphic.layer === states;
      })[0].graphic;

      view.whenLayerView(graphic.layer).then(function (layerView) {
        graphic.layer.renderer.symbol.color = 'orange';
        graphic.layer.renderer.symbol.outline.color = 'purple';
      });
     }
    });
  });
});
```

I can change the renderer and symbol, but I am looking to just change specific states:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way to change color of clicked state is to create clone of clicked feature graphic, set it's color to desired color and add it to the map view.

Logic of the sample code below is:

- only one state can be selected at one time;
- when new state is selected, previously select state graphic is removed;
- if selected state is clicked again, it is deselected.

```
const featureLayer = new FeatureLayer({
  url: "https://services.arcgis.com/V6ZHFr6zdgNZuVG0/arcgis/rest/services/OverlaySchools/FeatureServer/0",
  outFields: ["*"],
  title: "Private and Public schools in the US"
});

const map = new Map({
  basemap: "topo-vector",
  layers: [featureLayer]
});

const view = new MapView({
  map: map,
  container: "viewDiv",
  zoom: 4,
  center: [-98, 38.5],
  popup: {
    defaultPopupTemplateEnabled: false,
    dockEnabled: true,
    dockOptions: {
      buttonEnabled: false,
      breakpoint: false
    }
  }
});

let symbolSelected = {
  type: "simple-fill", 
  color: [ 51,51, 204, 0.9 ],
  style: "solid",
  outline: {  
    color: "white",
    width: 1
  }
};

let selectedGraphics = null;
let selectedId = null;

view.on("click", function (event) {
  view.hitTest(event).then(function (response) {
    if (response.results.length) {
      let clicked = response.results.filter(function (result) {
        return (result.graphic.layer.declaredClass == "esri.layers.FeatureLayer") || (result.graphic.layer.declaredClass == "esri.views.MapView");
      });       
      if (selectedGraphics) {
        view.graphics.remove(selectedGraphics);
        delete selectedGraphics;
        selectedGraphics = null;
      }
      if (clicked.length == 0) return;
      
      let graphic = clicked[0].graphic;
      let clickedId = (graphic.attributes) ? graphic.attributes.OBJECTID : null;
      if (!clickedId || (clickedId == selectedId)) {
        selectedId = null;
        return;
      }
      
      selectedId = clickedId;
      selectedGraphics = graphic.clone();
      selectedGraphics.symbol = symbolSelected;
      view.graphics.add(selectedGraphics);
    }
  });
});
```

That's how it looks like then:

[image]